# RDS user data and files on separate server

Tags: rds

we're in the planning stage to upgrade our old RDS server. The new server will be on Windows Server 2016 with plenty of RAM and SSD. Currently, our company files and redirected users' data are located on this one machine, on the D: drive. Would it be better for us to separate those data to separate machine instead of bunching it up together with the RDS server? If we do move the data to a dedicated file server VM, would it better to have multiple drive volumes? Such as a C: for OS, D: for company share files, and E: for folder redirection user data. Or can I just keep it all on the C: drive to save space. Or perhaps the folder redirection data for users need to be on the SSD to improve users' experience? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put the shared data (user profiles/folder redirection) onto a dedicated file server and use DFS if possible which will make it easier in the long term if you need to move the data to another file server. Also putting the shared data onto a dedicated file server means that if you need to scale the RDS environment later on it will be a lot easier.

You should also put the shared data onto a separate drive from the OS drive for example, C: for OS, D: for Shared Data. This will stop the file server from being crashed if a user gets happy and starts filling up the shared data.